# Spawn image at random position in canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, unity-ui

I have a **canvas** and inside it a **panel**. I want to **spawn** different **image UI object** at random position inside my panel (on screen). I took x and y min and max  limits of the panel in order to generate a random position (withing these limts) but the problem is object are not instantiating at desired position. This is my code.

```
public class ImageSpawnerScreen : MonoBehaviour {
    public float waitTime = 2;
    public float cubeSpawnTotal = 10;
    public List<GameObject> cubePrefabList;

    float xPosMinLimit = -347;
    float xPosMaxLimit = 340;
    float yPosMinLimit = -458f;
    float yPosMaxLimit = 450f;

    public GameObject panel;
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCube());
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnCube()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cubeSpawnTotal; i++)
        {
            GameObject prefabToSpawn = cubePrefabList[Random.Range(0, cubePrefabList.Count - 1)];
            //Vector3 spawnPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0,Screen.width),0,Random.Range(0,Screen.height)));  //Random.Range(xPosMinLimit, xPosMaxLimit);

            float xPos = Random.Range(xPosMinLimit, xPosMaxLimit);
            float yPos = Random.Range(yPosMinLimit, yPosMaxLimit);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0f);
            GameObject spwanObj = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            spwanObj.transform.parent = panel.transform;
            spwanObj.transform.position = spawnPosition;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I checked instantiated object positions are far away from the given random range position. What I am doing wrong? I think it is **Rect Transform** so i have to set its position differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage Canvas object's position you should definitely use `RectTransform` instead of regular `transform`. In your case you have to do something like :

`m_RectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();`

As for setting position - coordinates you see on the object inside Canvas is not `.position` but `RectTransform.anchoredPosition`, so you should use it in your code. Here is an official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) on `anchoredPosition`.

Comment: Well i have solve the problem using by setting locaposition instead of position (spwanObj.transform.localPosition = spawnPosition;). But your code is also worked for me. Thanks for valueable information. It is much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need to use `RectTransform` inside a `Canvas`.
You also don't need the `-1` for you `List.Count`. Check the link in the comment below.

I think the following script will do what you are looking for:

```
public class ImageSpawnerScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitTime = 2;
    public float cubeSpawnTotal = 10;
    public List<GameObject> imagesList;

    public RectTransform panel;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnImage());
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnImage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cubeSpawnTotal; i++)
        {
            GameObject imageToSpawn = imagesList[Random.Range(0, imagesList.Count)]; // Remove -1 after count since is exclusive for int (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

            Vector3 spawnPosition = GetBottomLeftCorner(panel) - new Vector3(Random.Range(0, panel.rect.x), Random.Range(0, panel.rect.y), 0);

            print("Spawn image at position: " + spawnPosition);

            GameObject spwanObj = Instantiate(imageToSpawn, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity, panel);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }

    Vector3 GetBottomLeftCorner(RectTransform rt)
    {
        Vector3[] v = new Vector3[4];
        rt.GetWorldCorners(v);
        return v[0];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ImageSpawnerScreen : MonoBehaviour {
    public float waitTime = 2;
    public float cubeSpawnTotal = 10;
    public List<GameObject> cubePrefabList;

    public GameObject panel;
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCube());
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnCube()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cubeSpawnTotal; i++)
        {
            GameObject prefabToSpawn = cubePrefabList[Random.Range(0, cubePrefabList.Count - 1)];
            //Vector3 spawnPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0,Screen.width),0,Random.Range(0,Screen.height)));  //Random.Range(xPosMinLimit, xPosMaxLimit);

            float xPos = Random.Range(0, Screen.width);
            float yPos = Random.Range(0, Screen.height);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0f);
            GameObject spwanObj = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            spwanObj.transform.parent = panel.transform;
            spwanObj.transform.position = spawnPosition;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }
}
```

This should help u out.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem.